# Is a couple who got divorced allowed to be together?

Tags: halacha, sexuality, divorce

Are a couple who divorced from each other allowed back together intimately?

Comment: http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=2/8/2011

Comment: Tov, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for the important question. I hope you stick around and enjoy [the site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Please note, though, that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends.

Answer (score 6):

If they are divorced then they are not married, and they certainly may not be intimate. 
Halachikally they are two strangers, and all of the halachos of yichud, etc. apply.
For cases where they are legally divorced but don't yet have a get, consult a Rav.

They may get remarried, unless the husband is a kohen, they got divorced because the woman committed adultery, or the woman married another man in the interim and he divorced her or died.

-Rebbetzin HaQoton

Comment: Yichud is actually more restrictive for them than regular strangers.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9728&st=&pgnum=9 EH 119:7 warns that after a divorce, they should not live in the same area because they may get together again (outside of marriage). The Chelkas Mechokayk explains because לבו גס בה The yichud itself is the same issue, but they may benefit from greater distance because they may still have strong feelings for each other.

Comment: Regarding a divorced couple, see Rambam (*Hil. Talmud Torah* [6:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=228), number 22 on the list of people liable for [*nidui*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herem_%28censure%29#The_niddui)). Regarding a couple who plan to get divorced, see Rambam (*Hil. Isurei Bi'a* [21:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=4511), ולא יבוא עליה אחר שגמר בלבו לגרשה).