# Can a divorced man sleep in the same household (no intercourse) with his ex-wife?

Tags: divorce, get

The man is visiting his kids, from another country, and will stay in the ex-wife's house.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Note we are not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: It is not definite that this is a personal question.

Comment: I am voting to re-open so we can close it again as a dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/133496/31534. This is not to be pedantic, but because then it will always be linked to the dupe and anything relevant will be shared between both questions.

Comment: @user34089, does the above link from RabbiKaii answer your question? It seems to be duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

This depends on a number of factors including the number of children present in the house, their ages and genders, and whether other people are as well.  This halacha applies for any non-related man and woman sleeping in the same house (Yichud) but is even stricter if they were married (thanks mbloch for the correction!) and it is best to consult your local Orthodox Rabbi for advice as there may be quite a few complicated details and different opinions.

Comment: Yichud is actually stricter for them than others, see e.g., https://outorah.org/p/21008/ and notes below https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43464/11501 - feel free to update and reflect some of this if you find it relevant

Comment: @mbloch corrected - thanks - I didn't know about that!